# How to get data for a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two pages (page1 and page2) with a `SimpleTable` component.

I have a page with a table for apples:

```
  render() {
    const props = this.props
    return (
      <Page {...props}>
        <SampleTable requestData={this.getApples} columns={[<columns for apples>]} />
      </Page>
    )
  }
```

And a page with a table for tomatoes:

```
  render() {
    const props = this.props
    return (
      <Page {...props}>
        <SampleTable requestData={this.getTomatoes} columns={[<columns for tomatoes>]} />
      </Page>
    )
  }
```

For reasons unknown to me, this particular child (`SampleTable`) is not being unmounted / mounted when I transition from page1 to page2 or vice-versa.

It is strange, since all the other children in all the other pages are being mounted / unmounted, even when I am using the same component for the children. So, clearly, I do not understand how / when does React decide to mount / unmount, or when does it decide to reuse a component. But I digress.

I will accept this fact: React will reuse children whenever it pleases.

My problem is that I am using `Sampletable.componentDidMount` to request data:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('SampleTable did mount. Requesting data ...')
    this.props.requestData(state.pageSize, state.page, state.sorted, state.filtered).then(res => {
      this.setState({
        data: res.rows,
        pages: res.pages,
        loading: false,
      })
    })
  }
```

But the function to request the data is provided by the parent, via `props`. I have the  following problem:

- on initial rendering, page1 provides a `requestData=getApples` via `props` to a `SampleTable` child.
- `SampleTable` mounts and requests the data, using the `getApples` method provided by `page1`
- I move to `page2`
- `page2` provides a *different* `requestData=getTomatoes` method to a `SampleTable` child
- somehow Reacts decides that it can reuse the original component for this child and, since it is already mounted, `componentDidMount` is not called
- and therefore, the new `getTomatoes` method is not called, and no data suitable for the tomatoes table is requested.

What am I doing wrong?

How can I ensure that the change in `props` is triggering a data reload?

Comment: Your question is not very clear to me. When you say page 1 and page 2, is it two different React Components you are talking about or its like pagination where component is same, you are chaning the data inside the Page component?

Comment: @ArpitAgrawal two different components, using the `Page` component

Comment: can you check, if `componentWillUnmount` is called when you move from 1 component to another component, Since you are rendering two different components?

Comment: @ArpitAgrawal I am not sure what you mean. In my original setup (without the `key= `), the child component was mounted once, and not unmounted anymore. Moving from `page1` to `page2` (both with a child based on the same `SimpleTable` component) was letting react reuse the child.

Comment: Lets not call them Page1 and Page2 because its confusing with Pagination or Page component. Since these are 2 different components, lets call them Component 1 and Component 2. Now my understanding of react says is when you move from C1 to C2, C1 has to unmount if they are different. if C1 and C2 are actually same, and you are passing different props only, then Component Will not unmount, instead `componentWillRecieveProps` method is called. It would be helpful if you could share some codesnippet.

Comment: @ArpitAgrawal I am as confused as you are, but reproducing the problem with a shareable snippet will take me a long time, which I do not have at the moment :(

Answer (score 1):

You should try using a unique key attribute on your SampleData component while calling it, so that react knows it a different instance of your component and re-render it accordingly.

You can find more about keys here: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: I thinks its intended for cases where you are rendering list of same components. I don't see the case here (there is no list here). It might solve the problem, but surely not the best way i guess.

Comment: I would really like to know the better way to solve this kind of problem. How would you solve it?

Comment: lets first figure out what the actual problem is. Since, he has two different component and moving from 1 component to another component should call componentWillUnmount, so i dont think its a case of react optimizing dom update. But lets wait for OP to reply.

Comment: I am not sure if this is the best way to solve the problem, but this approach solves it for me. The component is then unmounted / mounted, which triggers data reload.

Comment: Yes, keys are intended for lists so that react knows when to update the DOM, as the list items are sibling components. In this case we have sibling components but they don't have to be in a list specifically.

Comment: It is strange, because the components are children of different parents. They should be different instances, but somehow react decides to reuse the child of one parent for the other parent, unless a key is provided. No idea what is going on, but using `key=` when declaring the child component in the parent solves the problem.

Comment: @MikailBayram if you have only 1 component and you are changing the props only, dont you think instead of unmounting and mouting again (which key attribute will do), you need to use `componentWillReceiveProps` and updated the state of the component once it receives new props?

Comment: @ArpitAgrawal that would also be a solution, but why? Why is react reusing a component child of one parent for another parent?

Comment: Thats is why i am asking, can you share a working codesnippet so we can debug what real issue is?

Comment: @ArpitAgrawal componentWillRecieveProps is deprecated, and is not reccomended to be used. And yes, I would like to see a snippet too!

Comment: @ArpitAgrawal I'll try to find some time to reproduce it. I'll write once I have it.

Comment: @MikailBayram i was giving an example. Obviously, it availability depends on which react version OP is using. If its deprecated in that version, some alternate functions must be available to solve the purpose. I am just saying instead of key, we should be using this approach, since only props are changing to why not use a optimized approach provided by react.

Comment: @ArpitAgrawal I get your point, I am curious now too. We gotta wait for the snippet I guess :D